# ReactNative FlatList not Rendering some items

Tags: javascript, performance, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am using FlatList in my react native app to show some data received from api, includes image url and title and description.

The problem is the flatList is not rendering some of the items when I scroll it fast before rendering completely(Means before showing everything)

[image: FlatList]

Here is my flatList Code (JSX):

```
 <FlatList
                style={{ paddingTop: 10 }}
                numColumns={2}
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
                data={this.state.newsData}
                renderItem={(rowData) => this.renderWantAdsScreenFlatListItems(rowData.item, rowData.index)}
                extraData={this.state}


            />
```

states :

```
state = {
    newsData: null,
    nextPageUrl: '',
    prePageUrl: '',
    counter: 0,
    pageNumber: 1,
}
```

and renderWantAdsScreenFlatListItems function:

```
renderWantAdsScreenFlatListItems = (rowData, index) => {
    return <FlatListItem
        style={{ flex: 0 }}
        navigation={this.props.navigation}
        img={rowData.image}
        title={rowData.title}
        body={rowData.body}
        width={screenWidth / 2 - 30}
    />
}
```

and I got the data in componentDidMount using axios:

```
componentDidMount() {

if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental && UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
}
LayoutAnimation.spring();

const { navigation } = this.props;
this.focusListener = navigation.addListener("didFocus", () => {
    if (this.state.counter === 0) {
        axios.get('api', {
        })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);

                this.setState({
                    counter: 1,
                    newsData: response.data.data,
                    pageNumber: response.data.current_page,
                    prePageUrl: response.data.prev_page_url,
                    nextPageUrl: response.data.next_page_url,

                })
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            })
            .finally(() => {
            });
    }
});
```

}

and here is my  FlatListItem Component:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Fonts } from '../../Fonts/fonts';
class ListItem extends React.PureComponent {


    showDetail = () => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('WantAdsDetailScreen', {
            image: this.props.img,
            title: this.props.title,
            body: this.props.body
        });
    }
    render() {
        const { img, title } = this.props;

        return (
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={this.showDetail}
            >
                <View
                    elevation={5}
                    style={[styles.container,
                    {
                        overflow: 'hidden',
                        borderColor: '#00cec9',
                        borderRadius: 5,
                        backgroundColor: "#F5FFFA",
                        margin: 10,
                        width: this.props.width,
                        height: this.props.width,

                        shadowColor: '#000000',
                        shadowOffset: {
                            width: 0,
                            height: 10
                        },
                        shadowRadius: 5,
                        shadowOpacity: 1.0 
 }
                    ]
}>

                    <Image
                        resizeMethod='resize'
                        source={{ uri: img }}
                        style={{
                            width: '100%',
                            height: '100%',
                            borderTopLeftRadius: 5,
                            borderTopRightRadius: 5,

                        }}
                    />
                    <View
                        style={{
                            position: 'absolute',
                            bottom: 0,
                            left: 0,
                            width: '100%',
                            flex: 1,
                            alignItems: 'center',
                            justifyContent: 'center',
                            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)',
                            height: '18%',

                        }}
                    >
                        <Text
                            numberOfLines={1}
                            style={[styles.costTextStyle, {
                                fontSize: 16,
                                fontFamily: Fonts.IRANSans_Light,
                            }]}
                        >{title}</Text>
                    </View>

                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity >
        );
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    costTextStyle: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        margin: 4,
        fontFamily: Fonts.AsapCondensed,
        color: '#fff'
    }
});

export default ListItem;
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Why you not putting loader and waiting for the data to be fully loaded?

Comment: How to know whether all of the items were rendered completely then dismiss the loader and show the items??

Comment: @A.Najafi you can put loader for individual item while rendering each item of flat list. you can use onLoad() of image to know finish loading event.